# How to pass correctly params to a soap webservice in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have this Request XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://pqjsalud/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:generaCitas>
      <arg0>
        <apeMaterno>AGUILAR</apeMaterno>
        <apePaterno>SALDAÑA</apePaterno>
        <aseguradora>40006</aseguradora>
        <nombre>MONICA VANESSA</nombre>
      </arg0>
    </ns1:generaCitas>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Using an online soap client I got the response normally:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:generaCitasResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://pqjsalud/">
            <return>45|85</return>
        </ns2:generaCitasResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Using PHP code I am trying to consume this web service with this code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('HERE-IS-MY-WS-WSDL-URL');

if ($client) {
    $soapParams = array(
        'apeMaterno'    => 'AGUILAR',
        'apePaterno'    => 'SALDAÑA',
        'aseguradora'   => 40006,
        'nombre'        => 'MONICA VANESSA',
    );

    $result = $client->__soapCall('generaCitas', $soapParams);

    var_dump($result);
}
```

But I got a "java.lang.NullPointerException", what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using a WSDL, you don't need `__soapCall()` just use `$client->generaCitas($soapParams);` This is a server error you're getting, so maybe you should be looking to the server to find out what the problem is. Are you authenticating properly? Without any way to test it would be difficult to tell what the problem is.

Comment: I tried that too but the results are the same in a Java.lang.nullpointerexception. using an online soap client working fine but if i tried un PHP i hoy the error